# Increasing Max Upload File Size on IIS7/Win7 Pro

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, upload

I'm setting up a server for a client (something I don't typically do), and I'm running into issues with uploading larger files (11MB). The server is running Windows 7 Professional with IIS added.

In web.config I've tried setting

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="65536" /> <!-- 64MB -->
</system.web>
```

... and that doesn't work.

I've set

```
<system.webSecurity>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="68157440" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webSecurity>
```

... and that doesn't work either.

What am I missing here? As I've said, I don't typically set up servers, so I may be missing something obvious... no suggestion will be scoffed at!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out this was a problem with a component used on the front end.

It's worth noting (for anyone stumbling across this in the future), that the suggestions from both Jacob and Dan were required to make this work.

Thanks for your help anyway guys! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 13):

Change `system.webSecurity` to `system.webServer`.

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="52428800"/>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

If that doesn't work (due to permissions ramifications), set it using appcmd from an elevated command prompt:

> appcmd set config "wms/wmsdev" -section:requestFiltering -requestLimits.maxAllowedContentLength:52428800

More info here: http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/ramon/archive/2009/03/13/how-to-enable-large-file-uploads-in-iis7.aspx

Comment: heh, thanks. I actually was sys.webServer ... that was a typo manually copying from the other screen.

Answer (score 3):

In the event that it's timing out, I'd add `executionTimeout=”50000″` to your httpRuntime element.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Jacob, but still no luck.