# website not allowing large file uploads

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I've got an ASP.NET website that was running on IIS 6 and worked great.  We allowed our customers to upload large files (50MB+) without any issues.  We recently moved (my company) and our websites have been moved off-site as well (before they were on a server in our own building) and we had to switch from IIS 6 to IIS 7.  Since making the move, our website won't allow our customers to transfer large files.  I have tested smaller files (< 10MB) and they upload fine, but when I attempt anything over 10MB, I get the 404 Error:

`404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
 unavailable.`

We have the following in our web.config already:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1321600" />
```

Is there a setting in IIS 7 that I am missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increasing Max Upload File Size on IIS7/Win7 Pro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759461/increasing-max-upload-file-size-on-iis7-win7-pro)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to change this setting from web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000"/>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
</system.webServer>
```

More info here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942074/

Comment: Hi Bobek, what does the "524288000" relate to in Mb?

Answer (score 0):

The upload limit is stored in your machine.config.

You can override this in your web.config like so:

```
<system.web>
        <httpRuntime executionTimeout="110" maxRequestLength="20000" />
</system.web>
```

You can find more info about this in [this MSDN document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Comment: We have this in our web.config already....sorry, I meant to put this in my original post but forgot.

Comment: In that case bobek's answer will probably be what you're looking for.