# Call to WCF returns Request Entity Too Large

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, entity-framework, wcf-binding

I know this has been asked a few times but I have followed the given solutions and still getting the error.

I have a WCF Web Service Library, a WCF Web Service Host Application and a Windows Forms application that consumes the services.

The **Forms app** has a service reference to the host application with this App.Config....

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="BWData" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:58045/BWService.svc/bwd"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BWData" contract="BWServiceReference.IBws"
            name="BWData" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The **host application** Web.Config....

```
    <bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BWSBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483646"
      maxBufferSize="2147483646" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483646" maxStringContentLength="2147483646"
        maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="2147483646" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483646" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="MyApp.Business.WebServices.Bws">
    <endpoint address="bwd" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BWSBinding"
      name="BWData" contract="MyApp.Business.WebServices.IBws" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
```

With a SVC file....

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyApp.Business.WebServices.Bws" %>
```

The **WCF Service Library** App.Config ....

```
   <services>
  <service name="MyApp.Business.WebServices.Bws">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="MyApp.Business.WebServices.IBws">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/MyApp.Business.WebServices/Service1/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

I pass a large `List<t>` to the webservice that uses EF to add records to a database. Can anyone see what it is I am missing?

Comment: Try this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759461/increasing-max-upload-file-size-on-iis7-win7-pro

Comment: @Aron Thanks, gave that a go but still getting the same problem.

Comment: First, the config file for your service *library* is irrelevant - the library will use the config file for the hosting application.  Second, how big is the `List<T>` that you're trying to send?